# sort li element through date of li and move with it's full content jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to move the li element base on its newest date div. I have created this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjahav/hcw3d0nm/4/) as per this fiddle only dateDiv class moved but I want to move full sorted_li.

because of this issue, I have tried to use this script.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#exampleSelect', function() {
  var filter = $(this).val();
  if (filter == 'Newest') {
    var elems = $.makeArray($('.dateDiv'));
    elems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date($(a).text()).getTime();
      var dateB = new Date($(b).text()).getTime();
      return dateA < dateB;
    });
    $('.past-exams').html(elems);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="exampleSelect" class="form-control">
  <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
  <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
  <option value="Best">Best</option>
  <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
</select>
<ul class="past-exams">
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">40%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:58 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:15</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">10%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:19</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">20%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:13 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:03:18</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I don't understand how to move full sorted_li.

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 changes

- `var elems = $.makeArray($('.sorted_li'));`
- find :  `$(a).find(".dateDiv").text();`
- Correct sort functionality: `return dateB - dateA;` newest first

```js
$(document).on('change', '#exampleSelect', function() {
  var filter = $(this).val();
  if (filter == 'Newest') {
    var elems = $.makeArray($('.sorted_li'));
    elems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date($(a).find(".dateDiv").text()).getTime();
      var dateB = new Date($(b).find(".dateDiv").text()).getTime();
      return dateB - dateA; // newest
    });
    $('.past-exams').html(elems);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="exampleSelect" class="form-control">
  <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
  <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
  <option value="Best">Best</option>
  <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
</select>
<ul class="past-exams">
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">40%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:58 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:15</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">10%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:19</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">20%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:13 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:03:18</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But DRY - don't repeat yourself

```js
$(document).on('change', '#exampleSelect', function() {
  var elems = $.makeArray($('.sorted_li'));
  var filter = $(this).val();
  if (filter === 'Newest' || filter === 'Oldest') {
    elems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date($(a).find(".dateDiv").text()).getTime();
      var dateB = new Date($(b).find(".dateDiv").text()).getTime();
      return filter === 'Newest' ? dateB - dateA : dateA - dateB;
    });
    $('.past-exams').html(elems);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="exampleSelect" class="form-control">
  <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
  <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
  <option value="Best">Best</option>
  <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
</select>
<ul class="past-exams">
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">40%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:58 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:15</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">10%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:19</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">20%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:13 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:03:18</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't there a 3rd change `$.makeArray($('.sorted_li'))`?

Comment: @mplungjan but this is not sorted by newest date.

Comment: @MNJ I added oldest now too

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply sorting on li elements instead of date elements and compare date inside li in the sort function. See below code

```
$(document).on('change', '#exampleSelect', function() {
          var filter = $(this).val();

          if (filter == 'Newest') {
            var elems = $.makeArray($('.sorted_li'));

            var sorted = elems.sort(function(a, b) {
              var dateA = new Date($(a).find('.dateDiv').text()).getTime();
              var dateB = new Date($(b).find('.dateDiv').text()).getTime();
          //console.log(dateA + " and " + dateB);
              return dateA - dateB;
            });
            $('.past-exams').empty().append(sorted);
          }
        });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vfqkpcg1/2/)**

Comment: I was quicker :)

Comment: yeah, i was just few seconds behind :)